# задержка при выполнении chrome.tabs.getSelected

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь получить `tab.id`, используя вызов `chrome.tabs.getSelected` следующим образом:

```
var tabId = '';
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w){
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id,function(t){
    tabId = t.id + '';
    alert(tabId);
  })
});
alert(tabId);
```

При выполнении, сначала выполняется внешний `alert`, предъявляя пустое значение, потом внутренний, показывая искомый идентификатор. Введение задержки на внешний `alert` устраняет проблему, но не может являться решением. Насколько я понимаю для выполнения запроса создаётся отдельный поток, не синхронизированный с основным приложением.

Как правильно построить запрос, исключающий гонку потоков?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getSelected](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected):

> Deprecated since Chrome 33.

Эта функция устрела и не рекомендуется к использованию.

Вы можете использовать функцию [query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query). Что-то вроде:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {

    alert(tabs[0].id);
});
```

Получаем активную вкладку в текущем окне. Вы можете оперировать результатом в callback функции, которая передается в качестве параметра функции `query`.

> При выполнении, сначала выполняется внешний alert, предъявляя пустое
>   значение, потом внутренний, показывая искомый идентификатор.

Почитайте о [Asynchronous vs. synchronous methods](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#sync) на developer.chrome.com

Код

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w){
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id,function(t){
    tabId = t.id + '';
    alert(tabId);
  })
});
```

асинхронный. Т.е на момент вызова внешнего `alert'a` он находится в процессе выполнения и поэтому вы сначала получаете внешний `alert` с пустым значением, а после того как он отрабатывает вы получаете внутренний `alert` с желанным значением.

**UPD** к комментарию

> При всём уважении я не понял. Оперировать с tabId в пределах callback
>   функции не хочется, как вывести с помощью "другой функции",
>   принимающей tabId, не понимаю.

```
function someFunction(tabId) {
    // Делаем что-то с tabId.
    // Например
    alert(tabId);
}


chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {

    someFunction(tabs[0].id);
});
```

Или можно использовать `promise`:

```
function getTabId() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {

            resolve(tabs[0].id);

            // Может еще что-то. reject или..
        });
    });
}
```

Далее вызываем функцию `getTabId`

```
getTabId().then(function (tabId) {

    // Делаем что-то с tabId
    // Например

    alert(tabId);
});
```

Если кратко

`Promise` нужны для работы с асинхронным кодом.

В первой части мы написали функцию обертку, которая возвращает объект `promise`. Он принимает функцию обратного вызова с двумя параметрами - `resolve` и `reject`. `resolve` используем когда операция успешно завершена, т.е возвращаем результат с `tabId`. В случае каких-то ошибок используем `reject`.

Далее при вызове функции `getTabId` используем метод `then` который примает функцию обратного вызова с параметром `tabId` (его значение мы передали в resolve).

Про их использование есть хорошая [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/) (перевод). [Оригинал](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

И еще немного материала на MDN - [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Думаю этого хватит для понимания.

Comment: Я знаю об использовании chome.tabs.query, я также пытался использовать этот метод в альтернативу chrome.tabs.getCurrent, но поскольку он также является асинхронным, что подтверждается и  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#sync то ситуация остаётся прежней, хотя желательно было бы найти решение, позволяющее вывести tabId за пределы метода.

Comment: @avs100
Я же написал, вы можете выполнять действия с tabId в приделах callback функции, которая передается в query. Просто дерните из него другую функцию, которая будет принимать этот tabId.

Comment: При всём уважении я не понял. Оперировать с tabId в пределах callback функции не хочется, как вывести с помощью "другой функции", принимающей tabId, не понимаю.

Comment: @avs100 обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, ценная информация. Я новичок в JS, теперь думаю разберусь.